# Limit of $p$ norm as $p \downarrow 1$

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory

I had a question about the $p$ norm in the probability theory setting, which is the following:

Given a random variable $\xi$ such that $\mathbb{E} \xi^2 < \infty$, show that

$$\lim_{p\downarrow 1} (\mathbb{E}|\xi|^p)^{1/p} = \mathbb{E}|\xi|.$$

I can get that $\mathbb{E}|\xi| \leq \lim_{p \downarrow 1} (\mathbb{E} |\xi|^p)^{1/p}$ using an application of the Holder inequality but I'm not sure how to use the assumption that the $L^2$ norm is finite or the other direction of this inequality. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The finiteness of the $L^2$ norm is needed to show that $\Bbb E|\xi|^p$ exists for $p\leq 2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $1\le p\le2$, use
$$
\mathbb{E}\!\left(\left|\xi\right|^p\right)=\int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}\!\left(\left|\xi\right|\gt\lambda\right)\,p\lambda^{p-1}\mathrm{d}\lambda\tag{1}
$$
and Dominated Convergence.

---

**Getting $\boldsymbol{(1)}$ from the Usual Expected Value Integral**

The usual expected value for random variables that take non-negative values is
$$
\mathbb{E}\!\left(\xi\right)=\int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}(\xi\gt\lambda)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda\tag{2}
$$
Since $\left|\xi\right|^p$ takes non-negative values, we can apply the change of variables $\lambda\mapsto\lambda^p$:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\!\left(\left|\xi\right|^p\right)
&=\int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}\!\left(\left|\xi\right|^p\gt\lambda\right)\mathrm{d}\lambda\\
&=\int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}\!\left(\left|\xi\right|^p\gt\lambda^p\right)\mathrm{d}\lambda^p\\
&=\int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}\!\left(\left|\xi\right|\gt\lambda\right)\,p\lambda^{p-1}\mathrm{d}\lambda\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: So this version of the expectation comes from pushing forward the probability measure? Or is it some kind of density with respect to Lebesgue measure, because it looks like a derivative. I apologize if this question doesn't make sense but I just want to know why it can be written that way. Thanks.

Comment: We are using [this identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Continuous_distribution_taking_non-negative_values) (with a change of variables) and the fact that $\left|\xi\right|$ takes non-negative values.

Comment: @stlmagic: I have added a section on the change of variables in the integral.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up. So I would want to take $\lim_{p \downarrow 1}$ and pass it under the integral but that's where I need to use DCT right? I need to come up with some sequence of integrable functions dominated by an integrable function. I'm having trouble with this part.

Comment: $$ f(\lambda)=\left\{\begin{array}{}1& \text{if }\lambda\lt e^{-1}\\ -\frac1{e\lambda\log(\lambda)}& \text{if }e^{-1}\le\lambda\lt e^{-1/2}\\ 2\lambda &\text{if }e^{-1/2}\le\lambda \end{array}\right. $$ dominates $p\lambda^{p-1}$ for $1\le p\le2$.

Comment: [Animation for domination of $p\lambda^{p-1}$ by $f(\lambda)$](http://i.stack.imgur.com/efhn7.gif)